# Gnome control center fail on 17.04 ubuntu gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome-control-center

I cannot open the system settings.  When I run this in terminal

```
$ gnome-control-center
```

I get

```
(gnome-control-center:11494): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I run this as sudo, i.e.:

```
$ sudo gnome-control-center
```

the full information is

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(gnome-control-center:13379): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have tried purging and reinstalling gnome-control-center.  I have tried setting the environment variable to /run/user/XYZ.  I have tried removing the path to the Anaconda runtime.

My system has an nvidia 1070 card, runs at 128 Gb RAM with some 6960-ish intel processor of about 10 physical cores.  I cannot give exact details because the tool I usually use to show those is part of the gnome-control-center tools, and I cannot remember the details here.  I have a mostly fresh install of Ubuntu GNOME 17.04.  The exceptions are a few packages from the standard repository (Kile, KDevelop, cmake, gfortran, subversion, and a bunch more related to C++-programming and documentations of an extensive code-base with a bunch of computational libraries attached to it).  I also have Anaconda, Google Chrome, and Dropbox from outside the repository installed.

(I am completely new to gnome-desktop because of the upcoming abandonment of unity, so I might be missing the most basic of information here --- I cannot even figure out how to show the date in the clock in the menu! --- so please start from low levels.)

Help is most welcome!  I need to be able to change a few settings related to language settings.

Comment: try `setsid gnome-control-center`

Comment: Arduino_Sentinel, thank you!  This worked very well.  What can I have done to mess up the program so much?

Comment: not so sure,btw, there where some bugs report on early versions to.

Comment: @Arduino_Sentinel your command worked for me. But I works unexpectedly without any warning or errors (can't move from "Devices" section)

Comment: I had a similar problem with 16.04 and just restarted the computer :(